# Unbiased estimation of conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

Let X and Y be two independent discrete random variable. I want to find unbiased estimator of P[x|y]. I want a general expression that will still be applicable when a plug in certain distribution for X and Y.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If they are independent then $P(X \mid Y)=P(X)$